# Presto worker process mysteriously killed and restarted sometime

Tags: presto

In our presto cluster (0.212) with ~200 nodes (EC2 instances), sometime (like once per day) a few presto worker processes mysteriously restart (usually around the same time when it happens). The EC2 instances are fine and memory % metrics indicate 70% memory was used.

Does presto worker has any kind of suicide and restart logic (like restart if >= M consecutive errors in a row)? Or can presto coordinator restart worker under some situations? What else might kill a few worker process around the same time?

Here is one example of the server log that shows the restart.

```
2018-11-14T23:16:28.78011 2018-11-14T23:16:28.776Z  INFO    Thread-63   io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle stopping...
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17181 ThreadDump                      4524
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17182 ForceSafepoint                   414
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17182 Deoptimize                        66
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17182 CollectForMetadataAllocation        11
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17182 CGC_Operation                    272
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17182 G1IncCollectionPause            2900
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17183 EnableBiasedLocking                1
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17183 RevokeBias                      6248
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17183 BulkRevokeBias                   272
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17183 Exit                               1
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17183   931 VM operations coalesced during safepoint
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17184 Maximum sync time    197 ms
2018-11-14T23:16:29.17184 Maximum vm operation time (except for Exit VM operation)   2599 ms
2018-11-14T23:16:29.52968 ./finish: line 37: kill: (3700) - No such process
2018-11-14T23:16:29.52969 ./finish: line 37: kill: (3702) - No such process
2018-11-14T23:16:31.53563 ./finish: line 40: kill: (3704) - No such process
2018-11-14T23:16:31.53564 ./finish: line 40: kill: (3706) - No such process
2018-11-14T23:16:32.25948 2018-11-14T23:16:32.257Z  INFO    main    io.airlift.log.Logging  Logging to stderr
2018-11-14T23:16:32.26034 2018-11-14T23:16:32.260Z  INFO    main    Bootstrap   Loading configuration
2018-11-14T23:16:32.33800 2018-11-14T23:16:32.337Z  INFO    main    Bootstrap   Initializing logging
......
2018-11-14T23:16:35.75427 2018-11-14T23:16:35.754Z      INFO    main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle starting...
2018-11-14T23:16:35.75556 2018-11-14T23:16:35.755Z      INFO    main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle startup complete. System ready.
```

If relevant, these "./finish: ..." lines in the log are related to the the /etc/service/presto/finish file below.

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2     set -e
  3     exec 2>&1
  4     exec 3>>/var/log/runit/runit.log
  5 
  6     STATSD_PREFIX="runit.presto"
  7     source /etc/statsd/functions
  8 
  9     function error_handler() {
 10         echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ") Error occurred in run file at line: $1."
 11         echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ") Line exited with status: $2"
 12         incr "finish.error"
 13     }
 14     trap 'error_handler $LINENO $?' ERR
 15     echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ") process=presto status=stopped exitcode=$1 waitcode=$2" >&3
 16     # treat non-zero exit codes as a crash
 17     # waitcode contains the signal if there's one (ex. 11 - SIGSEGV)
 18     if [ $1 -ne 0 ]; then
 19         incr "finish.crash"
 20     fi
 21 
 22 
 23     # ensure that we kill the entire process group.
 24     # When sv force-restart runs, it will try to TERM the runit processes. If
 25     # this doesn't work, it will kill (-9) the process. In case of haproxy,
 26     # apache, gunicorn, etc., the master process will be killed (-9). Child processes
 27     # (ie apache workers, gunicorn workers) will *not* be killed and will be
 28     # around for minutes (if not hours). These child workers will keep
 29     # listening on the socket, preventing the new master apache/gunicorn
 30     # processes from binding to the socket. The new master process will keep
 31     # crashing and be restarted by runit until the old child processes are
 32     # gone.
 33 
 34     # determine the process group id. it's the group id of the current (finish) proces.
 35     PGID=$(ps -o pgid= $$ | grep -o [0-9]*)
 36     # kill all processes, except ourself and the PGID (which is the main process)
 37     kill $(pgrep -g $PGID | egrep -v "$PGID|$$" ) || true
 38     sleep 2
 39     # kill -9 to be sure
 40     kill -9 $(pgrep -g $PGID | egrep -v "$PGID|$$" ) || true
 41 
 42     echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ") process=presto status=finished" >&3
 43     incr "finish.count"
 44     timing "finish.duration"
```

Comment: What's the `./finish` shell script?

Comment: Edited the post to show the ./finish file content.

Comment: There is a system that force kills the JVM when an `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown.  This is a hard kill, so you would not get the `Life cycle stopping...` . That message is only printed from a JVM shutdown hook, so someone would have to send a kill signal to the process.

Comment: We found that our continuous pull deployment will restart the presto server under some conditions. It is however not 100% confirmed due to missing deployment log.

Answer (score 0):

Our continuous pull deploy (salt based) restarts the presto server process under some conditions (dependency or config change). It was undesirable and unintentional and related listen_in sections have been removed.